# Is it safe to manually remove entries on the db_schema_whitelist.json file?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, database, declarative-schema

I am wondering if it is safe to manually remove entries on the `db_schema_whitelist.json` file. I created a table called `customer_address_relationship` using the declarative schema approach and then I generated the `db_schema_whitelist.json` first and ran the `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command. The generated `db_schema_whitelist.json` file had the following entries:

```
{
    "customer_address_relationship": {
        "column": {
            "entity_id": true,
            "customer_id": true,
            "address_id": true
        },
        "constraint": {
            "PRIMARY": true,
            "CSTR_ADDR_RELATIONSHIP_CSTR_ID_CSTR_ENTT_ENTT_ID": true,
            "CSTR_ADDR_RELATIONSHIP_ADDR_ID_CSTR_ADDR_ENTT_ENTT_ID": true
        }
    }
}
```

I then later decided to change my approach to the problem at hand and had to drop the `customer_address_relationship` table (by removing it from db_schema.xml and generating db_schema_whitelist.json again and then running setup:upgrade). The better approach was to add a column instead to an existing table called `customer_address_entity` after adding the column in my db_schema.xml and generating the `db_schema_whitelist.json` file, the content of the file was now as follows:

```
{
    "customer_address_relationship": {
        "column": {
            "entity_id": true,
            "customer_id": true,
            "address_id": true
        },
        "constraint": {
            "PRIMARY": true,
            "CSTR_ADDR_RELATIONSHIP_CSTR_ID_CSTR_ENTT_ENTT_ID": true,
            "CSTR_ADDR_RELATIONSHIP_ADDR_ID_CSTR_ADDR_ENTT_ENTT_ID": true
        }
    },
    "customer_address_entity": {
        "column": {
            "address_type": true
        }
    }
}
```

Since I no longer need the table `customer_address_relationship`. Is it safe to alter the generated  `db_schema_whitelist.json` and remove its entries? What is the implication of this if there is any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current dual state where tables and columns can be added/altered/removed either via setup scripts (those located in the Setup folder) or via the new etc/db_schema.xml files, Magento can not know by itself which tables/columns can be safely altered using only the db_schema.xml files. Hence, the db_schema_whitelist.json holds a list of all the DB tables, columns, indexes, constraints, etc that were created via declarative schema and can therefore be safely altered in case it detects any change for those elements in an upgraded db_schema.xml file. Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: Thank you very much, this sure does make sense and it cleared a lot